# MySQL trying to count from two columns

Tags: mysql

I’m new at this so I’m having a hard time solving this problem, I’ve searched high and low but I can’t seem to find an answer.

This is how my tables look:

**Table artist**

| Columns | Constraints |
| --- | --- |
| Artist_id | PK |
| Name | - |

**Table song**

| Columns | Constraints |
| --- | --- |
| Song_id | PK |
| Title | - |
| artist_id | FK |
| co_artist_id | FK |

**Table top_list**

| Columns | Constraints |
| --- | --- |
| Id | PK FK |

I’ve made two foreign keys in the song table to the same primary key (`artist_id`). And also made a foreign key in `top_list` with `song_id`

My query is:

```
SELECT a.name Artist, COUNT(*) 
FROM top_list tl
INNER JOIN song s ON tl.id = s.song_id
INNER JOIN artist a ON s.artist_id = a.artist_id
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
LIMIT 1;
```

I want to count both the artist and the co-artist. ATM it only counts `song.artist_id` and not `song.co_artist_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly **count the artist**, then **count co_artists**. After that you can **sum them**.

This is '**artists**' table:

[image]

And this is '**songs**' table:

[image]

And the '**top_lists**' table:

[image]

And the query is:

```
SELECT artist AS Artist, SUM(amount) AS Amount
FROM (
    SELECT artist_id AS artist, COUNT(id) AS amount
    FROM songs
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM top_lists)
    GROUP BY artist_id
    UNION
    SELECT co_artist_id, COUNT(id)
    FROM songs
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM top_lists)
    GROUP BY co_artist_id
) AS inner_table
GROUP BY artist
ORDER BY Amount DESC;
```

The result is:

[image]

if you need you can do inner join to get the name of artists

And this is final query:

```
SELECT artists.name AS Artist, SUM(amount) AS Amount
FROM (
    SELECT artist_id AS artist, COUNT(id) AS amount
    FROM songs
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM top_lists)
    GROUP BY artist_id
    UNION
    SELECT co_artist_id, COUNT(id)
    FROM songs
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM top_lists)
    GROUP BY co_artist_id
) AS inner_table
INNER JOIN artists
ON artists.id = inner_table.artist
GROUP BY artist
ORDER BY Amount DESC;
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! It needs to be collected from the table top_list, I can't seem to make that work.

Comment: Could you clerify that what you need, it is not very clear what you want ?

Comment: Ok, now I know my question. My query is that I need to get the artist with most songs from the `top_list`, if I' not mistaken this provides the artist with the most songs from song, right?

Comment: Finally, problem is solved. Let's say it beginner technique )

Comment: I used 'id' column for ARTISTS table, BUT you've used artist_id. You can change it

Comment: Thank you for being so patient! I got it to work :D